# One element for navigation from all PanoramaItems

Tags: windows-phone-7, navigation

Panorama control is main view in my app. It has 3 `PanoramaItems`. I also have one Page which is kind of important for whole app. Because it is important I want to have possibility to navigate to that "important" page from each `PanoramaItem`.

I think this is task where `ApplicationBar` suits well. **BUT** I know that `AppBar` **shouldn't** be used on Panorama control at all.

Next solution I can think of would be some icon/button in each `PanoramaItem.Header`.

Are there any standard ways of doing this kind of navigation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put an icon in the header.  In my case it is a user tile, and tapping it logs you in.  I think it makes sense to put things that are global to the app up there in the header.

Comment: Thanks, I will do it most likely that way. I just wait a while before accepting.

Comment: Sure no worries.  Another question to ask your self is, "is Panorama the right control for my top level UI?"  I mean, the Twitter app uses Pivot... there is no law that says you have to use Panorama.

Comment: yes, that's good point. It's just....panorama is so new and nice... :D I really think it is quite good for my purposes but I definitely must consider other choices. thanks for comment.

Comment: "It's just....panorama is so new and nice" < really bad reason for doing something!

Comment: Yeah. No doubt about that. I was trying to make little joke... But I think good point was that even I think panorama is suitable for my purposes, I can look for other choices.